# How to use COUNTIF in Excel that is dependent on two conditionals?

Tags: excel

The first formula below is the one that operates correctly – its function is to tally up all “x’s” in a particular column when another column in that row says “Spain” and another column in that row says “Issued”.

```
=COUNTIFS(L$3:L$89,"=x",$A$3:$A$89,"=Spain",$H$3:$H$89,"=Issued")
```

The problem is with this next formula where I want it to do the same as above, plus add to it the tally for other rows that have “France”, for example. I know this formula isn’t structured correctly because the output is “zero”, when it should be “2”.

There are more countries that I want to add to this command eventually, but if I could get it to operate correctly with just two countries, adding the others should be easy. I’m not sure if the formula is the problem, or if I’m using the wrong function command, or what.

```
=COUNTIFS(K$3:K$89,"=x",$A$3:$A$89,"=Spain",$H$3:$H$89,"=Issued",K$3:K$89,"=x",$A$3:$A$89,"=France",$H$3:$H$89,"=Issued")
```

Comment: I recommend changing the title to something more meaningful and that pertains to your question. You are not going to attract people to your question with a title like that.

Comment: Although I say this and I read your question so maybe I'm wrong....

Comment: No worries - it was just my frustration coming through

Comment: You could just add the two COUNTIFS() together (one using Spain and the other France).  That will get a bit unwieldy as your list grows though.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

[image]

Entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Tim, it's been a little busy but I'll take a good look at this hopefully this evening.